# Killing all GPU process

Tags: nvidia, gpu

[image]

I want to kill all the GPU processes (as I have to install CUDA 10.0). What should I do?

Would be grateful for any help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stop Display Manager using `systemctl`. In my case it's `lightdm`:

```
sudo systemctl stop lightdm
```

Then switch to other terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>

After performing required actions, you could try to start it again by:

```
sudo systemctl start lightdm
```

All user's processes will be terminated.

To find out what display manager is used, run the next command:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

Comment: When I run the 1st command, I get the error:Failed to stop lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service not loaded.
Any help?

Comment: using systemctl status display-manager I get
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager

Comment: sudo systemctl stop GNOME : I get Failed to stop GNOME.service: Unit GNOME.service not loaded.

Comment: Use gdm or mdm or xdm instead